# Azure Blob Storage Error - The condition specified using HTTP conditional header(s) is not met

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-blob-storage

I have to save the LUIS intent in the Azure Blob storage. First time it is written in the File created in the blob container, but on the second time it gives me error.

Error Details -

The condition specified using HTTP conditional header(s) is not met.
RequestId:70a8fe02-801e-0071-5d92-06dbc0000000
Time:2021-02-19T07:42:49.0045165Z
Status: 412 (The condition specified using HTTP conditional header(s) is not met.)
ErrorCode: ConditionNotMet

Headers:
Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0,Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: 70a8fe02-801e-0071-5d92-06dbc0000000
x-ms-client-request-id: 4505eea2-d464-40b4-92b1-437789c65789
x-ms-version: 2019-07-07
x-ms-error-code: ConditionNotMet
Date: Fri, 19 Feb 2021 07:42:48 GMT
Content-Length: 252
Content-Type: application/xml

Blob Storage Container File Output - See the values

{"$type":"Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.DispatchBot+UtteranceLog, NLP-With-Dispatch-Bot","UtteranceList":{"$type":"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib]], System.Private.CoreLib","$values":["Hi","Luis - Chit_chat","What if there is a delay in Claim Intimation?"]},"TurnNumber":2,"ETag":""0x8D8D4B8353A37B4"","Timestamp":"2/19/2021 2:55:53 PM +05:30","ChannelId":"emulator","UserId":"","SourceOfResponse":"Luis"}

Comment: Hi All, Im using Bot Framework in C# to save the data of LUIS and QNA Maker

Comment: Could you please share the code that you write data to storage?

Comment: logItems = new UtteranceLog();

Comment: var _luisres = await DispatchToTopIntentAsync(turnContext, topIntent.intent, recognizerResult, cancellationToken);
             

                var changes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                {
                    changes.Add("UtteranceLog_" + member, logItems);
                }
                try
                {
                   
                    await _myStorage.WriteAsync(changes, cancellationToken);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }

Comment: var _luisres = await DispatchToTopIntentAsync(turnContext, topIntent.intent, recognizerResult, cancellationToken);             
                logItems.UtteranceList.Add("Luis - " + _luisres);
                var changes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                {
                    changes.Add("UtteranceLog_" + member, logItems);
                }
                try
                {                   
                    await _myStorage.WriteAsync(changes, cancellationToken);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {}

Comment: var _luisres = await DispatchToTopIntentAsync(turnContext, topIntent.intent, recognizerResult, cancellationToken);  logItems.SourceOfResponse = "Luis";
                logItems.UtteranceList.Add("Luis - " + _luisres);
                var changes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                {                    changes.Add("UtteranceLog_" + member, logItems);
                }
                try
                {                   
                    await _myStorage.WriteAsync(changes, cancellationToken);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)

Comment: @abhishek may I know how you solved this issue.